# Radio Buttons or checkbox with single selection on Datatables

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am using a datatable with checkboxes on the first column that permit multiple selection.

But now, I need that this checkboxes permit only single selection or it can be used a radio button on it.

This is the link to show my page http://cursosites-com-br.stackstaging.com/suporte_datatables.php

Can someone help me?

Regards,

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

I found an example on the comments of this link (https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-selection-using-checkboxes-and-select-extension/comment-page-3/#comments)

Very good!